# How to List Recursive Path in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, graph-traversal

I am trying to do a graph traversal where i want to list only the recursive path

My traversal has a variable depth of 1..10, which will find the followings paths:

```
1. start - decide - execute1 - end
2. start - decide - execute2 - decide - execute1 - end
3. start - execute3 - end
```

With the below query:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..10 OUTBOUND 'Node/start_0' Path
FILTER v.name == "end"
RETURN CONCAT_SEPARATOR(' - ', p.vertices[*].name)
```

Now i want to list only the path that has recursion or loop on it, in this example i want to get only the path `2. start - decide - execute2 - decide - execute1 - end` since it goes through `decide - execute2 - decide`.
I know we can avoid such loop Scenario by setting `uniqueVertices: 'path'` but how to get only the scenario that has loop in it